# How to condense multiple select count queries to increase code effiency?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I'm writing a ColdFusion page to generate an Excel table to look like this:[image]

I want to generate multiple columns of information from one table in the database. For each column I effectively need a SELECT COUNT to get the result. like this;

```
Select count (yT) as pageOneView from tTable where userGUID=#Query.guid# AND id='00101'

Select count (yT) as pageTwoView from tTable where userGUID=#Query.guid# AND id='00201'

Select count (yT) as pageThreeView from tTable where userGUID=#Query.guid# AND id='00301'
```

Note that the only details that change are the count name and the id. **How can I combine these into one `<cfquery>` instead of using a `<cfquery>` for each one?**

Comment: you want result in tabular form or in row form..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT in response to comment**

If you only want to show a "boolean" value then its inefficient to count all rows.

```
select
    case when exists
        (select * from tTable
            where guid = #Query.guid# 
                and yT is not null  
                and id = '00101')
        then 'True' else 'False' end pageOneView,
    case when exists
        (select * from tTable
            where guid = #Query.guid# 
                and yT is not null  
                and id = '00201')
        then 'True' else 'False' end pageTwoView,
    case when exists
        (select * from tTable
            where guid = #Query.guid# 
                and yT is not null  
                and id = '00301')
        then 'True' else 'False' end pageThreeView
```

---

like this,

```
select
        count(case id when '00101' then yT end) pageOneView,
        count(case id when '00201' then yT end) pageTwoView,
        count(case id when '00301' then yT end) pageThreeView
    from
        tTable
    where
        userGUID = #Query.guid#;
```

---

Note that [Andomar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275016/659190) uses less code and could be processed more efficiently by your SQL engine but, doesen't quite return a result set with the schema you wanted.

Comment: Also how could i display a boolean value if the count is greater than 0?

Comment: Also just realised this code doesn't account for the yT column.

Comment: @JackDamery The edit to the question shows a reasonably efficient way of checking for existence rather than counting.

Comment: *display a boolean value if the count is greater than 0* Keep in mind it can be done in CF code as well. If this is for `SpreadsheetAddRows`, simply return a `BIT` value, and it will be displayed as `true/false` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  id
,       count (itn)
from    tTable 
where   userGUID = #Query.guid#
        and id in ('00101', '00201', '00301')
group by
        id
```

Comment: But how can I an apply a name to each select?